# Calculate the array size according to remainder

Tags: java

There're a construction site and there're works to do. And we need certain number of workers to do them. Each worker has the same work capacity and they can't handle more than that limit. So for a given number of works, the number of workers required is :

- If the `works` is an integer multiple of `workerCapacity`, then `workers` will be a simple division of `works / workerCapacity`.
- If the `works` is not an integer multiple of `workerCapacity`, then after the division, we need to increment one. E.g. if capacity = 10, 100 works need 10 workers but 101 works need 11 workers.

Here's my implementation:

```
public int getNumWorkers(int works) {
    int workers = works / workerCapacity;
    if (works % workerCapacity != 0) {
        workers++;
    }
    return workers;
}
```

My question is: can we simplify the lines 2-5 into only one line ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. Add `workerCapacity-1` before dividing it out, like this:

```
return (works+workerCapacity-1) / workerCapacity;
```

If `workerCapacity` divides `works` evenly (i.e. `works % workerCapacity == 0`) adding `workerCapacity-1` will be too little to change the answer. If the remainder is above zero, adding `workerCapacity-1` will increase the result of division by one.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
return (int) Math.ceil((double) works / workerCapacity);
```

`Math.ceil` rounds it up any fraction to the next integer and it is clear than adding `workerCapacity - 1` to `workers`.

Comment: You answer is easier to read and understand. Maybe more appreciated when someone reads it.

Comment: Code is to be read by humans and eventually executed by computers. Readability is *the* key component in maintainability...

Comment: I totally agree with you. Although I accepted another answer, I'll take yours into my project.

Answer (score -1):

Just use this

return (int)(Math.ceil(works / workCapacity));

The Math.ceil method returns the next integer if the float isn't one

Comment: Then just do it like this

Comment: return (int)(Math.ceil(works / 1.0f / workCapacity));

Answer (score -1):

you can use the ? operator, so the function would look like :

```
public int getNumWorkers(int works) {
    return works % workerCapacity == 0 ? works/workerCapacity : 
    (works/workerCapacity+1)
}
```

assuming workerCapacity is an int variable declared in this scope.